# Problems with Scala Swing library

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-swing

Hello I am having problems when using the Scala Swing library in version 2.8 Beta1-prerelease. I have a situation where I want to show a table in GUI, and update it as results are returned from a SQL request. Which way could this be done in Scala, at the moment i am using the DefaultTableModel from Java library.

Another thing is that I want the table to be sortable afterwards, I cant see if Scala swing library supports this either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the scala swing library does not support sorting of `Table` - your best best is to revert to using `JTable` (i.e. the *java* swing class). A couple of things to note:

1. Don't use `DefaultTableModel` - use `AbstractTableModel` and implement the `getSize` and `getValueAt` methods. A table model should follow the *adapter* pattern
2. The appalling Java generics on the `RowSorter` are annoying when used with scala. You will have to use explicit generic type arguments