# Scala swing table - capturing column clicks

Tags: scala, swing

I am pretty new to both swing and scala, but I am trying to capture when a column is clicked in a scala.swing.Table and I have been unable to figure out how to do this. Can it be done in scala? I am still learning how to read the scala API, so any insight would be helpful,

Comment: you want to capture a random clic or want to get the selected row(s) and/or column(s)?

Comment: Sorry, I realized later that I should have been more specific. I read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342173/problems-with-scala-swing-library) that the scala table does not support sorting, so I wanted to write my own implementation, but I have been unable to determine when a column header is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Scala Swing doesn't support table header events yet, so you might have to do something like the following which adds a mouse listener directly to the **JTableHeader**.

I'm sure there is an elegant way to create a **scala.swing.Publisher** to integrate the listener with the **listenTo** and **reactions** mechanism, it just depends if it is worth the extra effort.

```
import java.awt.Dimension

import java.awt.event.{MouseEvent, MouseAdapter}
import swing._
import event.TableColumnsSelected

object TableQuestion extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  val headers = Array.tabulate(10){"Col-"+_}.toSeq
  val rowData = Array.tabulate[Any](10, 10){""+_+":"+_}

  lazy val ui = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
    val table  = new Table(rowData, headers)
    val label  = new Label("")
    val header = table.peer.getTableHeader()

    header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      override def mouseClicked(e: MouseEvent) {
        val col = header.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint())

        label.text = "Column header "+col+" selected"
      }
    })    

    listenTo(table.selection)

    reactions += {
      case TableColumnsSelected(_, r, _) =>
        label.text = "Column "+table.selection.columns.leadIndex+" selected, range = "+r
    }
    contents  += new ScrollPane(table)
    contents  += label
  }

  def top = new MainFrame {
    title         = "Table Column Selection"
    preferredSize = new Dimension(400, 260)
    contents      = ui
  }
}
```

Additionally I find the range information provided by the TableColumnSelected event rather strange, it contains contiguous column indices from the current click to the previous click in a different column. Perhaps I'm missing something as to why.

Comment: Thanks for your time on answering my question. This should get me enough of what I need.

Comment: I was able to take your example and make it work with scala Publisher and Reactors, see my answer. Its not perfect, but it works for my needs, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Pleased to be able to help. I hadn't realised that publishing was so accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to take the example by Don Mackenzie and produce something using a Publisher and Reactor.

```
import java.awt.event.{MouseEvent, MouseAdapter}
import javax.swing.UIManager
import swing._
import event.TableEvent

object TableQuestion extends SimpleSwingApplication
{
  val headers = Array.tabulate(10) {"Col-" + _}.toSeq
  val rowData = Array.tabulate[Any](10, 10) {"" + _ + ":" + _}

  lazy val ui = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
  val table = new Table(rowData, headers)
  val label = new Label("")
  val header = table.peer.getTableHeader()

  header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    override def mouseClicked(e: MouseEvent) {
       publish(ColumnHeaderClicked(table, header.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint())))
    }
  })

  listenTo(table)

  reactions += {
    case ColumnHeaderClicked(_, column) => label.text = "Column header " + column + " selected"
  }
  contents += new ScrollPane(table)
  contents += label
}

  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName);
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Table Column Selection"
    preferredSize = new Dimension(400, 260)
    contents = ui
  }
}   

case class ColumnHeaderClicked(override val source: Table, column: Int) extends TableEvent(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't write your own implementation of table sorting - use [GlazedLists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/) instead.  You will thank me.  You'll probably need to use a standard JTable rather than a swing.Table, but it can handle all of the sorting and filtering you will ever have to do.

Comment: Wow, I have never seen that library before. I played with it for a bit, but I ended up using mostly pure java and java swing code and thats not the point of my playing with scala.